# Listen to object instantiation

Tags: c#, .net, object, garbage-collection

I have interface and some classes that implement this interface.
I want to listen for any object that will be instantiated and check if this object implements my interface.

My primary reason is to store all references to this kind of objects and simply call a method of interface to all objects.

Comment: The easiest way to accomplish this would be to use an abstract class instead of an interface. Then just add your code in the class's constructor.

Comment: The problem is that I have many derived classes from other classes so I can't change the base class. Interface is my only solution

Comment: Well I'm fairly certain that's the only way to attach custom behavior to the instantiation of anything.  The only other option is to create everything via factory methods and make the normal constructors private or protected.

Comment: Listen to @Kyle. He gave you all you can do

Comment: @T.S. yes but it is not enough

Comment: Then you need to modify internals of .net to create built-in such functionality :-)

Comment: Then I'm afraid you've got a fundamentally flawed design.  C# gives you a mechanism to attach behavior to instantiation: the constructor.  If you're unable to change the design of your system to use the constructor then the only option left is to simply accept that the user of your library will have to remember to register objects themselves.  It's not a great solution, but you're kind of painted into a corner here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kyle said in the comments the constructor of an abstract class would be the best choice. Or a factory that must be used for construction of those kind of objects.

But if this is not an option maybe the following approach is acceptable in your case.

If the "listener" is globally accessible (e.g. something static) you can add methods like `Register(IYourInterface obj)` and `Unregister(IYourInterface obj)` to it and ensure that every class that implements the interface will call these methods on construction / deconstruction. Not the cleanest way, but it will work as long as you maintain this behavior.

**Example:**

```
public static class Listener
{
    private static List<IMyInterface> objects = new List<IMyInterface>();

    public static void Register(IMyInterface obj)
    {
        if (!objects.Contains(obj))
            objects.Add(obj);
    }

    public static void Unregister(IMyInterface obj)
    {
        if (objects.Contains(obj)
            objects.Remove(obj);
    }

    public static void DoSomethingWithObjects()
    {
        foreach (IMyInterface obj in objects)
            // do something ...
    }
}

public class SomeTestClass : IMyInterface
{
    public SomeTestClass()
    {
        Listener.Register(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it is good solution, but every class that implements that interface must call Register method that we can't ensure to happen, we can't force the class to call it and at some point developer may forget to call that method :(

Comment: Ok. It was not clear that someone else than you works on this code. So I presented this solution. If it doesn't fit, nvm.

Comment: Is there no way to listen to object initialization globally? like to subscribe to system event or something?

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go about this.

### Use a base abstract class

Easiest solution is to have a base class that everything inherits from. This kind of defeats the purpose of the interface, but this is the only way you can add this sort of code for creation. You could do something like:

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseClass
{
    public AbstractBaseClass()
    {
        ObjectRegister.StoreReference(this);
    }

    public abstract void MethodToCall();
}

public class SubClass : AbstractBaseClass
{
    public SubClass() : base() //Don't forget 'base()'!
    {
        //Your code here
    }

    public override void MethodToCall()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called in SubClass");
    }
}
```

The abstract MethodToCall could also be virtual if you want to provide a default action, but if it's abstract the compiler will complain that you haven't implemented it in a similar way to interfaces.

### Use a public static instantiating method

A bit more verbose, but can be seen in things like Unity. In this case, instead of doing `x = new Y()`, you have a public static method, perhaps a generic one, that creates the class for you, registers it, then returns that instance. Assuming your interface is called 'IRegisterable', you could have something like:

```
public static class ObjectRegister
{
    //Note the 'where', which constrains T to be something that
    //implements IRegisterable 
    public static T Instantiate<T>() where T:IRegisterable
    {
        T obj = new T();
        StoreReference(obj);
        return obj;
    }

    private static StoreReference(IRegisterable obj)
    {
        //Do your storing code here. This doesn't even need to be a method
        //if your reference storing stuff only happens on object creation
    } 
}

//Elsewhere, where class 'Thing' implements IRegisterable

Thing x = ObjectRegister.Instantiate<Thing>();
//x is now registered. No need to do x = new Thing()

string y = ObjectRegister.Instantiate<string>();
//Error: string does not implement IRegisterable
```

Unfortunately, supplying constructor arguments this way isn't easy. You could just have an Init() method though which acts as a sort of fake constructor.

Comment: where T:IRegisterable - does not work because T could be IRegisterable or it may have private constructor, or it may be abstract class so new T() could not be called

Comment: In the case that you might have private constructors and such, then I'm afraid you're going to have to rely on Robert S's method and just make sure that the developers call Register on each instance that's created.


As far as I'm aware, there's no event and no other way of detecting when new is called on objects in C# without the use of a factory method or base constructor for everything that needs to know.